# How to simplify notation for the Kronecker product of multiple matrices?

Tags: matrices, notation, kronecker-product, kronecker-symbol

I would like to know if I can simplify notation for the Kronecker product of multiple matrices:

$$A = A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n$$

For example, I could use a product sign such as:

$$A = \otimes\prod_{i=1}^n A_i$$

However, I am not sure if this is the standard way of doing it?

Comment: You can use $$\bigotimes_{i = 1}^{n} A_i.$$

Comment: This is the standardized notation?

Comment: I would say it is.  It's the only notation I can remember seeing.

Comment: I have used the very same notation in my dissertation and in publications. I would say it's quite standard. It would still deserve an explanation in the introduction of whatever you are writing.

Comment: I think that this is standard, in the same way that you write $\bigotimes_{i=1}^n V_i$ for the tensor product $V_1\otimes \cdots \otimes V_n$ of vector spaces. You can go further and write $A^{\otimes n}$ in the case that $A\doteq A_1=\cdots = A_n$. But as Florian says, it is always good to briefly explain it before you dive into results.

Comment: Thanks! Do you also know how can I write that a matrix, e.g., $(A_2)_{p\times q}$ has the same size as matrix $(A_1)_{m\times n}$, i.e. $p=m$ and $q=n$, but without using variables $p,q,m,n$, just the symbols for $A_1$ and $A_2$?